# php file not accessible when url typed in to browser

Tags: php, ftp, http-status-code-404

I tried to search for this on the forums, but I don't know exactly what my issue is called. I hope this isn't redundant to another forum or a really stupid question. This is also my first post, so I read through what I need to put in this question, but please help me learn if I forgot to include something.

I FTPed a .php file over to my server into the /public_html folder which is where my index.php file are as well as everything else that I can get to show in my web browser (chrome). The file is named **game-response-confirmation.php**. I have the permissions for this file set to 777 on the server as well just for testing purposes (i'd like to set them back to 644 when I'm done if that doesn't have to do with the issue).

The issue is when I type in the url **www.mywebaddress.com/game-response-confirmation.php** into the address bar, I receive a 404 Not Found error. It says that the file was not found on this server.

To be honest, I'm not sure what other information you need to help troubleshoot this issue with me. Ask and I will provide more information.

For this, I would expect the page game-response-confirmation.php to appear as a webpage in the browser. Currently, the website is a simple echo since I needed to make sure it wasn't the php file that was creating the problem.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to make sure it really is spelled EXACTLY like that.  Case sensitive and all.

Comment: Try going to `/public_html/game-response-confirmation.php`, i dont know what else could be wrong :p

Comment: I think it would be helpful to provide the hosting that you are using and webserver if you know it. Do you have ssh access to the server or only ftp?

Comment: the other pages are working (i.e. you can navigate to every individual page that's in that folder except the one you are having trouble with)?  If the index.php is your only other point of entry, it might be that everything is routed to your index.php page with url rewriting, so check your .htaccess.  Otherwise, no clue.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - good thought. I definitely did that about 100 times to make sure I wasn't nuts. :) we've all done that at one point I feel.

Comment: @Thaillie - I tried that as well. Once it didn't work as expected, I went to every level of the path to see if it was something weird with the server and the filepath.

Comment: @somdoron - I do have ssh access to the server and am able to access and run the file from ssh access through my terminal

Comment: @KevinNelson - good thinking. I did check .htaccess and it actually has some weird results in it. I'm looking into that now to see if has any info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at ".htaccess" file. Perhaps there is wrong redirection inside. 
For instance:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Third line obtains all URLs and sends them to unknown place. In result you get error #404.

Comment: the .htaccess file looks like this when i open it from the server:

Comment: The .htaccess file looks like this when i open it from the server:  RedirectMatch \.(dynamiccontent|pl|plx|perl|cgi|php|php4|php5|php6|php3|shtml)$ http://okapi.arvixe.com/cgi-sys/movingpage.cgi. It looks like the host may be migrating servers. They are in the middle of migrating still and I have not received information for the new server. If I had put this new file onto the old server after they migrated everything else to the new server, would that potentially cause this error?

Comment: Golka had a great suggestion. going into the htaccess file givs some information about what is going on. It told me, indirectly, that my host was switching over the server. So I was able to investigate and figure out that they are in the middle of the migration. Because of this, I didn't have the new server information and was uploading the .php page to the old server while the domain was pointed to the new server. So of course this file wasn't available! Silly. Thank you all for suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

Golka had a great suggestion. going into the .htaccess file gives some information about what is going on. It told me, indirectly, that my host was switching over the server. So I was able to investigate and figure out that they are in the middle of the migration. Because of this, I didn't have the new server information and was uploading the .php page to the old server while the domain was pointed to the new server. So of course this file wasn't available! Silly. Thank you all for suggestions and help.